# Calculate used percentage of RAM in AIX servers

Tags: shell, memory, aix

I am using the below script to calculate the total,used and free memory.
FYI..

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

used_memory=`svmon -G | head -2|tail -1| awk {'print $3'}`
used_memory=`expr $um / 256`

total_memory=`lsattr -El sys0 -a realmem | awk {'print $2'}`
total_memory=`expr $tm / 1024`

free_memory=`expr $tm - $um`
```

Is this the correct way of finding free RAM..!?

I also do not understand why we are dividing `used_memory` by 256.
Please help me here..!

Comment: You might get an explanation of the values shown by svmon by reading the manpage or asking on [stackexchange's serverfault](http://serverfault.com/) - this question is not strictly about programming but about understanding of tools of professional computers

Answer (score 0):

I got it..!

svmon display output in pages..! 1 page=4kb
thanks..!